# How to make div with left side text and right side Image Bootstrap 4

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

Here is Image in this image you will found left side some text like name, address and right side image of that person. So please tell me how i will make this with bootstrap 4

[image]

Comment: Show us what you have tried, StackOverflow is not a coding service

Comment: fun fact: they actually made that site with bootstrap. you can inspect it and copy classes to your liking.

Comment: I recommand you use bootstrap card...

Comment: How to copy classes? Please tell me

Comment: @AftabAnxari  . See my answer

Comment: @לבנימלכה I see bootstrap card but it provide facility image on top

Comment: that the reason I use `col-sm-6` and warp div see in my answer

Comment: it is possible in card img in right side? @לבנימלכה

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can use bootstrap-4 `card` and `col-sm-6` to each part**
**See here:https://jsfiddle.net/9k8w1fpq/4/** 
Learn about card:https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_cards.asp

```css
img{
width:100px;
height:100%;}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="card" style="width:400px">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <img class="card-img" src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg" alt="Card image"/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="card-body-right">
      <h4 class="card-title">John Doe</h4>
      <p class="card-text">Some example text some example text. John Doe is an architect and engineer</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">See Profile</a>
    </div>
     </div>
  </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is my answer

Comment: No reason to add this as comments, just edit your answer

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen the PO asked me in comment below question

Comment: Thank you verrrr Much brother. Please little bit more how to center these 3 card? @

Comment: `justify-content:center;` to `row`

Comment: @לבנימלכה please tell me how to center these 3 card in center of row

Comment: in row class div add this in style justify-content:center

Comment: @לבנימלכה Brother i need 3 card in single row. Please brother

Comment: increase the screen to see it in big size